# Safely using raw pointers obtained from unique_ptr or shared_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

In trivial examples, it is easy to say

> "Use `shared_ptr` when you want to share the resources and `unique_ptr` for unique ownership, otherwise pass `const &` or `*` to access the pointers"

In non-trivial code (in my case, game engines) there are many areas where:

- It is not easy for a library class to predict whether a `shared_ptr` or a `unique_ptr` of an object will be passed. This is especially problematic if the the library class stores pointers to the objects for whatever reason.
- An object can sometimes be a `shared_ptr` and sometimes a `unique_ptr`, depending on its usage.
- Users screw up all the time (which could be me, using my own game engine)

Thus, most of the time, raw pointers are being passed around and then sometimes stored by the user (or even the library itself - which may not be good design, but with non-trivial code, this becomes common practice otherwise a change in the underlying interface is necessary).

Using raw pointers can (and does) result in undefined behavior whenever the user attempts to dereference the raw pointer when the object has been destroyed either by `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`. Tracking down the source of these bugs (who deleted what and when) is a nightmare, especially with a corrupt call stack.

One *could* use `weak_ptr` for some scenarios and obtain a `shared_ptr` safely, but not only are `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` heavy-weight compared to raw pointers (or `unique_ptr` for that matter), it cannot be predicted whether an object was stored as a `shared_ptr` all the time. Perhaps it was stored as a `unique_ptr`.

**So then my question** is, can one construct a semi-smart pointer e.g. `safe_ptr` where a `shared_ptr` *or* a `unique_ptr` can be converted to a `safe_ptr` i.e. `safe_ptr` becomes the default access for all smart pointers. The `safe_ptr` itself gets compiled out to a raw pointer in release builds, but in debug builds it provides valuable information when the pointer is dereferenced in cases where the object has been destroyed by `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` and triggers a debug break (the program was going to crash anyway with undefined behavior!)

Comment: I think what you want is actually `std::weak_ptr` or at least a wrapper using it for debug mode. I cannot really think of a safe _less heavyweight_ (I don't really believe it is) implementation of `safe_ptr`.

Comment: I would use the primitives how they were designed. If performance is an issue you can look at running with an address sanitizer.

Comment: A knife is a useful tool but it can kill. You can try to make it safe but it will also remove its usability. Therefore it stays as it is. How could it be otherwise. Raw pointers are fine mostly. Smart pointers are about stating ownership explicitly.

Comment: _@Samaursa_ Well, I just see that [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/weak_ptr) doesn't work with `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Can't you use something like this? `template<class C, class D> std::shared_ptr<C> shared(std::unique_ptr<C, D> &ptr) { return std::shared_ptr<C>{ptr.release(), ptr.get_deleter()}; }`

Comment: @skypjack you can but then the library code needs to have this everywhere? And then more code to react to the fact that the `unique_ptr` is gone?

Comment: I understood that the problem was that sometimes you got an unique instead of a shared one...

Comment: @CharlesBeattie An address sanitizer? Is there one for Windows? From my experience, trivial memory leak detectors slow the game down to a crawl (impossible to test) let alone something like an address sanitizer. And I agree that we use the primitives the way they were designed - I am asking if a new one, `safe_ptr`, can be written such that the mentioned requirements are met.

Comment: @skypjack Right, sometimes the library is holding onto the pointer uniquely and gives the user access to it - the library did not predict how the user was going to use the pointer (and end up storing it long term) - the library at some point deletes the object when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope. The user then attempts access and things break badly. One could say "don't do that", but aren't a lot of these constructs made to avoid saying "don't do that" in the first place? Rust, for example, is taking that approach.

Comment: @Samaursa Consider the fact that a lot of null pointer dereferencing and other nasty stuff often strongly depends on timing. I've had applications that only crashed (sometimes untraceable) in debug mode while others only crashed in release mode (RelWithDebInfo didn't crash either). So testing in debug and also using other types than in release might make your development even more difficult.